# How to show the row number in the XamDataGrid?

Tags: wpf-controls, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Could someone please tell me if there is a simple way (e.g. boolean property to set) to get the Infragistics WPF XamDataGrid to show the row number?

I found something in the feature browser, but that seems to be for the XamGrid. We use the WPFv3 11.2 libraries.

Some quick Googling seems to indicate that the feature isn't supported, but the latest post seems to be in 2011.

Comment: Probably you have already seen this post on Infragistics Support Forum, however [this is the link](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/52722/278616.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did see this. I mean to ask if there was a simple way to do this, and I've edited the question for clarity. If you're sure there isn't a simple way, please post an answer and I'll mark it as accepted and up-vote it.

Comment: I will wait some days before making my comment as an answer because there are other people here that monitor this tags and perhaps they are better at xamDataGrid than me.

Comment: @Steve you should make your comment the answer as it is a feature request for a property to make it easy to do this.  The feature can be requested by contacting Infragistics on the forums or by submitting a support case and you can find links to each on the get help page:  http://www.infragistics.com/support/get-help.aspx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of the NetAdvantage Suite (2011 vol. 2), there isn't a property that can be used to accomplish your requirement.
A solution exist that create a specific class implementing the IMultiValueConverter interface as explained in [this thread](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/52722/278616.aspx) on the Infragistic Support Forum.
You could submit your requirement to the Infragistics Dev Team using the [Feature Request link](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBase.Aspx) on that page, as other reviewers have already done.

*(thanks @alhalama)*

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late, but in case, you still haven't found a solution:

- In the base class which form the objects inside the binding list, create a property for the column which will display the row number
- Create another property of Visibility type inside your view model, which will be used to show/hide the row number column
- Create a static resource for the view model inside your view
- Bind the visibility property of the row number column to the Visibility property created inside the vm file

You should be set.